# IAT hook is not working with notepad.exe on Windows

Tags: c, windows, hook

When I inject this DLL via the conventional `LoadLibrary` method, the DLL is injected and when I attach it to the process (notepad.exe) and run it in a debugger, it seems to work.
However, when I type some characters in Notepad or save the file to disk, it calls the original `WriteFile` function, not the custom Hook function.

When I perform these actions in notepad and monitor it via rohitab's API monitor, notepad calls the native `NtWriteFile` when I type something (it saves the data to a temporary file) and it calls `WriteFile` when the user saves the file manually on disk.

Anyway, someone once said that possibly loaderlock occurs, is that the case? I don't call one of these functions from DLL main though? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices

Can someone please help me? I'm not a pro in **C**, so maybe I made some rooky mistakes but can't find them..

*Note: for some reason, when I remove the `fprintf` statements, I get an error:

> "Debug assertion failed"

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>


    FILE* file_pointer;
    FILE* write_file;
    HMODULE array_modules[1024];
    DWORD number_bytes;
    DWORD WB = 0;
    WCHAR BUFFER[1024]; //Unicode characters
    int i;
    char BUFFER_OUTPUT[] = "test1"; //Unicode characters
    typedef int(WINAPI* Func_Pointer)(HANDLE, LPCVOID, DWORD, LPDWORD, LPOVERLAPPED);
    Func_Pointer Original_VA_WriteFile = NULL;
    
    
    
    BOOL WINAPI WriteFile_HOOK(HANDLE hFile, LPCVOID lpBuffer,
        DWORD nNumberOfBytesToWrite, LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
        LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
    {
    
    
        fopen_s(&write_file, "C:\\Users\\Mikail\\Documents\\outputinjectedDLL7.txt", "w+");
        fprintf(write_file, "test");
        fclose(write_file);
        return Original_VA_WriteFile(hFile, lpBuffer, nNumberOfBytesToWrite, lpNumberOfBytesWritten, lpOverlapped);
    
    
    
    }
    
    
    
    BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE Base_DLL_Address, DWORD Reason_CALL, LPVOID Reserved)
    {
        switch (Reason_CALL)
        {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    
    
    
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "OK", "01", MB_OK);
            Original_VA_WriteFile = WriteFile;
            DWORD PID = GetCurrentProcessId();
            HANDLE Handle_Process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, PID);
            if (Handle_Process == NULL) {
                DWORD error = GetLastError();
                fprintf(file_pointer, "Handle not retrieved %s", error);
            }
            else {
                fopen_s(&file_pointer, "C:\\Users\\Mikail\\Documents\\outputinjectedDLL10.txt", "w+");
                fprintf(file_pointer, "\nVA of WriteFile_HOOK is :%p", WriteFile_HOOK);
    
    
    
                char* ImageBase = NULL;
    
    
    
                if (EnumProcessModules(Handle_Process, array_modules, sizeof(array_modules), &number_bytes) != 0) {
                    for (i = 0; i < (number_bytes / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++) {
                        DWORD Module_LEN_string = GetModuleFileNameEx(Handle_Process, array_modules[i], BUFFER, sizeof(BUFFER));
                        if (wcsstr(BUFFER, L"Notepad.exe") != NULL) {
                            ImageBase = array_modules[i];
                            fprintf(file_pointer, "\nImagebase: %p", ImageBase);
                            PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeaders = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)ImageBase;
                            fprintf(file_pointer, "\ndosHeader: %p", dosHeaders);
                            PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD_PTR)ImageBase + dosHeaders->e_lfanew);
                            fprintf(file_pointer, "\nntHeader: %p", ntHeaders);
                            IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY ImportsDirectory_RVA = ntHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT];
                            PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR Import_Directory = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)(ImportsDirectory_RVA.VirtualAddress + (DWORD_PTR)ImageBase);
                            fprintf(file_pointer, "\nImport Directory: %p", Import_Directory);
    
    
    
                            while (Import_Directory->Name != NULL)
                            {
                                char* Module_AA = (char*)(ImageBase + Import_Directory->Name);
    
                                PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA OFT_value = (LPCSTR)Import_Directory->OriginalFirstThunk; //RVA_OFT
                                PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA PointerModule_AA_OFT = (LPCSTR)Import_Directory->OriginalFirstThunk + (DWORD_PTR)ImageBase; //VA_OFT
                                PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA PointerModule_AA_FT = (LPCSTR)Import_Directory->FirstThunk + (DWORD_PTR)ImageBase; //(R)VA_FT
    
                                if (strstr(Module_AA, "KERNEL32.dll") != NULL) {
                                    while (PointerModule_AA_FT->u1.Function != NULL) {
    
    
    
                                        PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA Win32_Function_AA_FT = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)PointerModule_AA_FT->u1.Function; //AA WIN32 Function
                                        PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA Win32_Function_RVA_OFT = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)PointerModule_AA_OFT->u1.Function; //RVA WIN32 Function
    
    
    
                                        PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME functionName = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)((DWORD_PTR)ImageBase + PointerModule_AA_OFT->u1.AddressOfData);
    
    
    
                                        if (strstr(functionName->Name, "WriteFile")) {
    
    
    
                                            DWORD OR_Access_Rights;
    
    
    
                                            int VirtualProtect_Memory = VirtualProtect(&Win32_Function_AA_FT->u1.Function, sizeof(DWORD_PTR), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &OR_Access_Rights);
                                            if (VirtualProtect_Memory == 0) {
                                                fprintf(file_pointer, "\nVirtualProtectMemory FAILED");
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                fprintf(file_pointer, "\nVirtualProtectMemory SUCCEEDED: %d", VirtualProtect_Memory);
                                            }
    
                                            Win32_Function_AA_FT->u1.Function = (DWORD_PTR)WriteFile_HOOK;
                                            if (Win32_Function_AA_FT->u1.Function == (DWORD_PTR)WriteFile_HOOK) {
                                                fprintf(file_pointer, "\nAddress stored in IAT %p", Win32_Function_AA_FT->u1.Function);
                                                fprintf(file_pointer, "\nAddress of WriteFile_HOOK %p", WriteFile_HOOK);
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                fprintf(file_pointer, "\nHOOK FAILED");
                                            }
    
    
    
                                        }
    
    
    
                                        PointerModule_AA_OFT++;
                                    }
                                }
                                Import_Directory++;
                            }
    
    
    
                        }
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
                    }
                    return TRUE;
                }
                ;
            }
        }
    
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Notepad is not a good choice to test this on Win11.  Use Settings > Apps > Advanced app settings > App execution aliases > off for Notepad.

Comment: Okay, could you please explain why notepad is not a good choice and why I need to adjust the setting, thanks!

Comment: It is quite visible when you try it.  With Off selected you actually run notepad.exe.  But the default is to actually run another .exe file (the alias), the appx version of Notepad.  Which won't have the hook.

Comment: Your code formatting is all over the place; I can't be bothered to read this code. Please remove all these big blocks of empty lines and maybe consider using functions, so that you won't end up with some 10+ levels of nesting.